# How can I make autocomplete in the shell work with case-folding?

Tags: bash, command-line

How can I make the autocompletion for files and folders in the bash shell work case-insensitively?

Ideally, `cd ~/doc` + <kbd>tab</kbd> autocompletes to `cd ~/Documents` (correcting the case as it autocompletes), but if that's not possible autocompleting to `cd ~/documents` is acceptable too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by typing the following command in the terminal:

```
echo 'set completion-ignore-case On' >> ~/.inputrc
```

if you want to go back to the original behavior you have the open that file and remove the line.

The file `~/.inputrc` file deals with mapping the keyboard for specific situations. This file is the start-up file used by Readline, the input-related library used by Bash, perl and most other open source programs.

> The configuration options in .inputrc are particularly useful for
>   customising the way Tab-completion works, e.g. with the ls command
>
> When a program which uses the Readline library starts up, the init
>   file is read, and the key bindings are set.

You can find more information about the file syntax in "[Bash startup files](http://ss64.com/bash/syntax-inputrc.html)".

Comment: Ty, this works. Out if curiosity, is there a reason why this doesn't work when added to ~/.bash_profile for example?

Comment: @Gerry I noticed the same by adding it to `.profile` (correct it if I'm wrong). In my opinion this is because Readline read the `.inputrc` or `/etc/inputrc` and not other files. However I'm not completely sure about that.